# Development environment for Cloudera

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, cloudera

I'm a beginner in Big Data development and nowadays I'am using Cloudera services in a shared environment where I'm building spark scripts for data ingestion using Jupyter notebooks, but I'm not sure if is a good approach because I miss IDE resources such as code completion, auto import, debugger and others.
Lately I tested pycharm to try build some scripts, but I can't config it to consume remote resources.
How do they suggest? I already build some scripts with Jupyter, but I think with other approachs I can be more productive.

Comment: What did you configure? What are you trying exactly to achieve? Can you show us the code? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for reply @Adonis, in truth my problems is not about code. I already created some scripts for data ingestion, but I'm not confortable with Jupyter, because when I need to do more complex tasks it's not so efficient for me, in other words it has limited resources in code completion, doc and others. I look for suggestions about alternatives like pycharm for example I'm suposing integrate with Jupyter

Comment: From my own experience, when abandoning Jupyter, Spider is a nice alternative. Now unfortunately StackOverflow is not dealing with recommendations, you might want to have a look at Quora, and if you have a specific issue that you cannot resolve, post it here then

Comment: Thank you @Adonis, I understood your point, you are right.